# Can I run a while loop inside a for loop? [Java] If so, how would I do it in this scenario?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

Im doing some simple maths using loops and my task is as follows:

"Given an integer,N , print its first 10 multiples. Each multiple N * i  (where 1 <= N <= ) should be printed on a new line in the form: N x i = result."

My input has to be :

```
N
```

My output:

```
Print 10 lines of output; each line 'i' (where 1 <= N <= ) contains the result N * i of  in the form: N x i = result.
```

Sample Input:

```
2
```

Sample Output:

```
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
2 x 10 = 20
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        
        for (int i = 0; i >= 1 && i <= 10; i++){
            
            
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Would I be able to use a while loop to state the the integer, N, should be able to print out all the numbers in the inclusive range of 1 to 10  to the calculation of the (sample) input: 2x1=2. 2x2=4 etc.

If I can do it without the while loop i.e just using the for loop or for-each, please advise on how I can do it. Im really confused with this. Thanks.

Comment: "Can I run a while loop inside a for loop?" Yes. You can have as many nested control structures and loops as you like.

Comment: So there is no need to use 'break' or 'continue' to stop the loop then continue with another while or for loop?

Comment: No, you can have as many loops as you want inside another loop

Comment: Yeah, I believe C has some limit of 128 nested things, but in Java there's only the memory limit, and realistically you're never, ***ever*** going to want to be nested that deep. And, again, you _can_ use `break` and `continue` in nested loops, but you don't _have_ to. Worth noting that they only break or continue the loop they're directly in, not the outer ones.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense now. Thanks you for the clarification

Comment: In `` for (int i = 0; i >= 1 && i <= 10; i++){`` the ``i >= 1 &&`` will cause bugs, because it will cause the loop to fail the first time through. Just use ``i <= 10``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't see the problem, you don't need a while loop at all, you just need simple maths:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        
    // I removed the i >= 1 because it hinders the for loop from even staring,
    // you had i = 0 before, so the i >= 1 would output false. So the for loop would stop
    // instantly. You can just start the loop with the number 1 so you dont multiply by zero.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(N + " x " + i + " = " + (N * i));
        /*
        lets say N is 2, then it will output the following:
        2 x 1 = 2
        2 x 2 = 4
        2 x 3 = 6
        2 x 4 = 8
        2 x 5 = 10
        2 x 6 = 12
        2 x 7 = 14
        2 x 8 = 16
        2 x 9 = 18
        2 x 10 = 20
        Just as you want it to.
        */
    }
    
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, others have also been saying that while loop is not needed. thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand you want to show the mult table of a number, showing multiples from 1 to 10 of a given number. What i dont understand is why you need a while inside the for, as you have the base number (input) and a constant for loop (1 <= N <= 10). If i understood well the question, this is the code you need to achive this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
    
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
            System.out.println(String.format("%d x %d = %d", n, i, n*i);
        
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Reading your question the comment from @Toastrackenigma is the right answer, yes you can use nested while or for loops inside other loops. What you need to do is to be more clear in your questions to obtain better help from the community

Comment: Thanks for this, I was confused at first whether I should or shouldn't, I tried it as well but gave me an error.

Comment: By the way, you got a compilation error: variable 'n' is not defined, its actually the upper case N, but I see where you came from and your answer is right nevertheless

Comment: The compilation error is because i changed your N to n as it is a variable and not a constant, and due to naming conventions, variable attributes may be named with camel case lower case names and constants (variable marked as final) with full upper case names. If you copy /paste the code i posted there is no compilation error. Its only you missed up that change :)

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting that haha. I also did the same thing as you when I encountered the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;



public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
        
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println(n + " x " + i + " = " + n*i);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```